# How to compare vertices of two graphs and assign community membership of the first graph to the second graph, in igraph?

Tags: r, graph, igraph

My question is how to compare vertices of two graphs, and assign community membership of the first graph to the second graph, using igraph in R.

Please consider this example:

```
karate <- graph.famous("Zachary")
g <- graph(c(17,1, 2,1, 32,2, 5,2, 3,1, 33,3, 30,3, 33,3, 21,3, 4,3, 25,4, 10,4, 
             18,5, 6,7, 8,4, 11,1, 6,11, 13,1, 13,4, 14,4, 14,4, 14,5, 15,7, 17,7,
             18,2, 20,1, 12,24, 26,1, 31,2, 32,1, 19,33), directed = FALSE)

V(g)$name <- V(g)              
wckarate <- walktrap.community(karate)
V(karate)$name <- V(karate)
V(karate)$comm <- membership(wckarate)
```

Solution 1, too slow for big graphs:

```
for (i in 1:length(V(karate))) {
  for (j in 1:length(V(g))){
    if (V(karate)$name[i] == V(g)$name[j]) {
      V(g)$comm[j] <- V(karate)$comm[i] 
    }
  }
}
```

Solution 2, convert to data frame to use `dplyr`:

```
A <- data.frame(Name = V(karate)$name, Comm = V(karate)$comm, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
B <- data.frame(Name = V(g)$name, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
B <- left_join(B, A)
```

But in this solution I don't know how to create the graph from the data frame containing vertex      names.

Could anyone suggest another solution? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I see you've been a member for 4 months. You really need to be more careful posting code. For one thing there's a syntax error (missing comma in the definition of `g`), so the code does not run. For another, you compare the vertex names of `g` and `karate`, but you never set the vertex names of `g`, so they are all `NULL`. Always run your code before posting and then cut/paste.

Comment: @ jlhoward, really sorry, thanks for your advice, please see the code once more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest is

```
V(g)$comm <- V(karate)[ V(g)$name ]$comm
```

This solution assumes that the vertices of `g` are all included in `karate`. What happens here is that you can index a vertex sequence of a named graph with a character vector, and then the specified vertices are selected:

```
V(karate)[ V(g)$name ]
#> Vertex sequence:
#>  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
#> [26] 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33
```

Then you can just select the `comm` attribute of these vertices, and then you'll get `comm` in the order of the `g` vertices.

If you want to set this only for the common vertices, that is simple, too:

```
common <- intersect(V(g)$name, V(karate)$name)
V(g)[common]$comm <- V(karate)[common]$comm
```

Comment: Csradi,Thank you so much,sorry for late comment.that was so helpful, I have two other question : how to check whether all the node are included in the other graph or not, and what is the solution for that case, could we first assign $comm to other thing and then use this command?

Comment: thank you @Gabor Csrdi, for my first question I find the answer I could simply use : `all (V(g)$name %in% V(karate)$name)`

Comment: What do you want for vertices in `g` that are not in `karate`?

Comment: Csradi, for example to assign their own membership group first and then assign membership group of `karate` to the vertices which are common with `g`. code continue : `wckarate1 <- walktrap.community(g)  V(g)$name <- V(g) V(g)$comm <- membership(wckarate1) and then V(g)$comm <- V(karate)[ V(g)$name ]$comm `